# TikZ node too tall

Tags: beamer, tikz-node

I want to be able to "gray" out sections of my beamer lectures (based on some expiration time predicate).  With some very useful help from this forum I'm almost there.  My solution is to define a new "expire" environment and place the text (could be math equations) in a TikZ node within this environment.  Sadly the node consumes more height than I would like.  In the slide below I would ideally like the grayed out box to be one line high.  Is this fixable?

Many thanks.
[image: grayed out single equation]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{environ}            % for the 'expire' idea
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewEnviron{expire}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=gray!40, inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0pt]{%  %gray!40
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        {\color{black}
          \BODY
        }
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Exponents}
\[ x^{a}x^{b} = x^{a+b} \]
\[ \frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b} \]
\begin{expire}
\[(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}\]
\end{expire}
\[ x^n + x^n = 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\color{black}` and use options `[align=center,minimum width=\textwidth,text=black]` on the node

Comment: Do I not need the minipage in the case that I want to boxify a math environment, say?  By replacing {\color{black}...} with [...,text=black...] the box has become neater but there's still a noticeable gap above/below it.  Perhaps this is unavoidable...

Comment: align=center forces TikZ to use a minipage already to typeset. The other space comes from the above and below math skips

Comment: Use `\textcolor{red}{\neq}`.

Answer (score 4):

As percusse said, you don't need a `minipage`. Moreover, I would use `gather*`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\expire}[1]{%
  \tikz{%
    \node[fill=gray!40, inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
        gray!40, text=black, minimum width=\textwidth]{$#1$};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exponents}
\begin{gather*}
x^{a}x^{b} = x^{a+b}\\
\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}\\
\expire{(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}}\\[-4pt]% or any other dimension you prefer
x^n + x^n = 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n} 
\end{gather*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution could be a TikZ `matrix of math nodes` with a node style to put before the row you want to be gray (see `|[expire]|` here):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{%
    expire/.style={
        fill=gray!40,
        text=black,  
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exponents}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[matrix of math nodes, nodes={inner xsep=0pt,
                minimum width=\textwidth}] {
                x^{a}x^{b} = x^{a+b}\\
                \dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}\\
                |[expire]|(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}\\
                x^n + x^n = 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n}\\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want both text and math:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{%
    expire/.style={
        fill=gray!40,
        text=black,  
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exponents}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={inner xsep=0pt,
                minimum width=\textwidth}] {
                Here something\\
                |[expire]|not in math mode\\
                $x^{a}x^{b} = x^{a+b}$\\
                $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$\\
                |[expire]|$(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}$\\
                $x^n + x^n = 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n}$\\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but both of those solutions expect a math argument.  I would like to be able to place /arbitrary/ text in the box and have it disappear according to some predicate.

Comment: @healyp That's not a problem, use a `matrix of nodes` instead of a `matrix of math nodes` and put `$... $` in the node which have math text.

Comment: @healyp See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

with simple `tabular` and `\rowcolor`

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Exponents}
\[  \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft$}p{0.475\linewidth}<{$} c >{$}p{0.475\linewidth}<{$}}
x^{a}x^{b}      & = & x^{a+b}\\
\frac{x^a}{x^b} & = & x^{a-b}\\[1pt]
\rowcolor{cyan!40}
(x^{a})^{b}     & = & x^{ab}\\
x^n + x^n       & = & 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n}
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `tcolorbox` package could be an alternative:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{expire}{colback=gray!40!white,boxrule=0mm,arc=0mm,top=0.25mm,bottom=0.25mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Exponents}
\[ x^{a}x^{b} = x^{a+b} \]
\[ \frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b} \]
\begin{expire}
\[(x^{a})^{b} = x^{ab}\]
\end{expire}
\[ x^n + x^n = 2x^n {\color{red} \neq} x^{2n} \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice but the alignment is lost.